# How to improve the code to get a list from a csv with a condition?

Tags: python

Good morning,

I was refactoring a code I developed long time ago,

I have a CSV with two columns, one for accounts and the other one a boolean to identify if the account is active:

| accounts | active |
| --- | --- |
| 213233 | 0 |
| 333222 | 1 |
| 222111 | 1 |
| 344561 | 1 |

I did the next:

```
df = pd.read_csv(accounts_csv_path)
active_accounts = df[df["active"].isin([1])]["account"].tolist()
```

I would get a list *active_accounts*

```
['333222','222111','344561']
```

But something is telling me it could be done better.

1. First at all, in the column **active** it would be better have *true* / *false* than *1* / *0* ?
2. Maybe find a way without use pandas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that this is code that is already working, you may want to consider [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: `pandas` is your bestfriend, maybe you can consider `active_accounts = df.loc[df['active'] == 1, 'account'].tolist()` when working with csv in Python

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We [do not want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) your "thanks in advance" as it is assumed, and we are not having a conversation. But more to the point, improving the style of already working code is off topic here. If you specifically want a non-Pandas way to get the result, we can deal with that, but we need a much clearer and more direct specification for **what should happen** when the code is run.

Comment: "in the column active it would be better have true / false than 1 / 0 ?" - rather than asking us, why not **try it** and see if it offers a simplification? (Alternately: if you had some simplification in mind, first try and see **whether it already works** with the 1/0 values.)

Answer (score 1):

Using .isin() takes a list as an argument, in your case [1]. However, using a list seems unnecessary if it just contains one item.
This will also do the trick:

```
df[df["active"] == 1]
```

To only get the accounts column, the following can be done:

```
df.loc[df["active"] == 1, 'accounts']
```